# Casp to Escape mapping gets reverted behind the scenes

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, capslock, gnome-tweaks

On 20.04 LTS, pretty vanilla setup, I've successfully managed to remap caps to escape using gnome-tweaks... except it doesn't stick. *Something* unknown to me reverses the setting after a few hours or days.

Before I go down to putting a cron job that calls `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"` every minute -- how do I figure out what's obnoxiously undoing my settings?

Comment: You may have encountered [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206).

Comment: Yep, dead on. I have a USB matrix to switch between laptop and desktop. Switching triggers the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Any chance you can help by testing the proposed fix? Please see comment #29 in the bug report.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it does fix the problem for me!

Comment: Nice. I mentioned your confirmation in the bug report.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caps-lock remapping stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286997/caps-lock-remapping-stops-working)