# Swapping Control and Caps Lock on Dell XPS on 20.04 - used to work with gnome-tweaks

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-tweaks

With 18.04, I could use gnome-tweaks to swap Control and Caps-Lock keys and it persisted beyond suspend/resume and reboots. Now, in 20.04 it does not persist. Even suspend wipes it out.

Most of related questions on this topic are out of date.

Comment: Probably related questions:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286997/caps-lock-remapping-stops-working
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291175/casp-to-escape-mapping-gets-reverted-behind-the-scenes

Comment: Same problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298182/gnome-tweaks-reset-after-lock-screen/1307657#1307657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206 . There is a bug fix moving in the release chain. In the mean time, you can resolve it by downgrading the mutter version as given in the bug dialog:

1. Set up this PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~gunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/mutter](https://launchpad.net/%7Egunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/mutter): `sudo apt-add-repository -u ppa:~gunnarhj/mutter`
2. Install the given version of mutter: `sudo apt-get install libmutter-6-0=3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.3~ppa2`
3. Reboot is necessary

Comment: Installing from the PPA is not to downgrade. It's the official version `3.36.6-1ubuntu0.20.04.2` plus a couple of upstream commits.

Comment: Unable to locate package libmutter-6-0

Comment: Did you install the PPA (step 1). It is still there