# Remapping Caps Lock behavior does not persist

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell, gnome-tweaks

I use Gnome Tweaks Tool 3.34.0 (and GNOME Shell 3.36.4) and under "Keyboard & Mouse" I change via "Additional Layout Options" the "Caps Lock Behavior" to be swapped with Escape key.

[image: Screenshot of the tweak tools settings]

Yet while this works for a while, the setting often undoes itself and I don't know why. The setting is seen as toggled, but the default behavior of the button is restored.

How can I make the swap permanently?

The issue occurs often when I lock the screen and login. Also, I have an USB switch to use my input devices at another PC. So it may have to do with the unlpugging the keyboard and then restoring the connection.

---

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: @guiverc Your expectection is correct. I wrongly copy pasted the GTK version instead of the Gnome Shell one.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291705/159370) to the other question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Currently, there is only a workaround posted, and while it helps, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I see you found my answer at last. :)