# Restart Gnome process for keyboard config only?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg, keyboard-layout

I'm using a laptop with a detachable screen, anytime it detaches my custom keyboard settings stop working (inverted scrolling, caps remapped as hyper, etc). I can get them back by rebooting my system or running `gnome-replace --shell`, but both of these are inconvenient as they take time to log back in and cause me to lose all of my open applications.

Does anyone know how I can restart the daemon responsible for keyboard configuration specifically? A command I can run to quickly fix the problem without relogging?

Comment: Do the answers here, especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291705/159370) answer your question? [Caps-lock remapping stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286997/caps-lock-remapping-stops-working)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes! Thank you, `alt+f2` 'r' worked.